# Why is PyCharm saying a section of my code within a funciton is unreachable, despite it is working as intended?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have this code that checks internet connection and sets a boolean accordingly.  I've put the code in a function.  But PyCharm is showing that this line:  "start_time = time.time()" is unreachable.  Did I write my code wrong?

Screenshot:  [image: pic of warning]

The code:

```html
from time import time, sleep
import os


def something():
    while True:
        sleep(2 - time() % 2)
        ip_list = ['8.8.8.8']
        for ip in ip_list:
            response = os.popen(f"ping {ip}").read()
            if "Received = 4" in response:
                print(f"UP {ip} Ping Successful")
                _connected = True
                print(_connected)
            else:
                print(f"DOWN {ip} Ping Unsuccessful")
                _connected = False
                print(_connected)


    start_time = time.time()

    seconds = 1

    while True:
        current_time = time.time()
        elapsed_time = current_time - start_time

        if elapsed_time > seconds:
            print("Finished iterating in: " + str(int(elapsed_time)) + " seconds")
            break


something()
```

My end goal here is to understand why PyCharm would call this warning.  It seems to me that everything is correct.

Comment: Your `while` loop is infinite, so the control flow never reaches that point.

Comment: Believe PyCharm.  It knows Python better than you do.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you have any way to break out of your while loop. You probably need a break statement in there.